# How to insert the currentUser email into the Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, react-native

Everytime i tried inserting the users email into the database, there will be an error saying "First Arguement is an invalid path".How do i get pass this

```
return (

  <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Rate this Song</Text>
    <Text style={styles.textStyleSmall}>  {list.title}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.textStyleSmall}>  {list.artist}</Text>
    {/*View to hold our Stars*/}
    <View style={styles.childView}>{React_Native_Rating_Bar}</View>

    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
    {/*To show the rating selected*/}
      {this.state.Default_Rating} / {this.state.Max_Rating}
    </Text>

    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={0.7}
      style={styles.button}

      onPress={() => {
        firebase.database().ref("Song title: "+ list.title +''+ "Artist: "+ list.artist + currentUser.email).set({Ratings : (this.state.Default_Rating)})
        alert('Thank you')}
    }>        
      <Text>Continue</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Text>
     {currentUser && currentUser.email}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

}

The expected result is when i view the database in firebase, the users account name should be there alongside with the title an artist name

Comment: What exactly is this line of code supposed to do?  `firebase.database().ref("Song title: "+ list.title +''+ "Artist: "+ list.artist + currentUser.email).set({Ratings : (this.state.Default_Rating)})`?  That's a very unconventional looking database reference.  What does it mean for the account name to "be there"?

Comment: the database ref is to insert the title of the song, the artist and also the currentuser email. I can insert the title and the artist of the song just fine. I just have issues with inserting the currentUser into the database

Answer (score 0):

The way you are creating your song ratings key is error prone because you are not checking if it conforms to the [limitations of a Firebase database key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#data_tree):

> 1. Maximum 768 Bytes
> 2. Keys are UTF-8 encoded and can't contain new lines or any of the following characters:
>      . $ # [ ] / or any ASCII control characters (0x00 - 0x1F and 0x7F)

You are already certainly breaking the second constraint since email addresses are containing at least one `.` character.

```
firebase.database().ref("Song title: "+ list.title +''+ "Artist: "+ list.artist + currentUser.email).set({Ratings : (this.state.Default_Rating)})
```

Consider sanitizing the data before using it as a key or finding a structure where you don't use arbitrary data such as "song titles" and "artist names" to become keys without first being sanitized.

**Sidenote:** you probably don't want to store all data as "root nodes" in your database. Consider structuring them under a "ratings" node first.

If all you need is a unique key to directly address a user's rating for the current song by a certain artist, then you can create a hash over that string to create a valid Firebase key.

```
firebase.database().ref("ratings").child(MD5(list.title + list.artist + currentUser.email)).set({Ratings : (this.state.Default_Rating)})
```